# Suit a problem to the equation $\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i} {n \choose i} = 0$

Tags: combinatorics

I need to think of a proper and a creative problem in order to prove the next equation in a combinatoric way: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i} {n \choose i} = 0  $$

I want to use the Inclusion–exclusion principle to prove it but can't think of a proper problem that suits to this equation.

Comment: I assume $n$ is positive. Try to count all elements $x \in \left\{1\right\}$ that satisfy none of $n$ given tautologies. (Or, equivalently, that satisfy all of $n$ given false statements.)

Comment: Are you asking us to prove the equation or to find a question which uses it?

Comment: @Wen first I need a proper question that it's solution suits to this formula. then I'll try to solve it myself, if I get in some trouble, I'll ask

Comment: As an aside, if you just want *any* proof, one can recognize that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(-1)^i1^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}=(-1+1)^n=0$ (*for $n>0$*)

Answer (score 1):

The number of even and odd sized subsets of a set with at least one element are the same.

Comment: Can you provide an example?